# How to apply a scrollbar on a jframe that has multiple buttons

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener, jscrollpane

I am creating a frame what will display a list of Jbuttons that show that location of some products. The reason I want this list to be buttons is to link them to other frames if they are clicked. I would like to know a way to have a scrollbar that can go through the entire list. The Code I currently have is below:

```
enter code here
import javax.swing.*;//window settings
import java.awt.*;//font settings
import java.awt.event.*;//action settings
public class locationFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    Font tFont=new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,46);
    Font bFont=new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,52);

    JLabel Title=new JLabel("Enid's Picks");
    JLabel label=new JLabel("");
    Image img=new 
    ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/HPMLOGO.png")).getImage();
    JButton backButton=new JButton("Go Back");
    JButton AlemaniButton=new JButton("Alemania");
    JButton ArgentinaButton=new JButton("Argentina");
    JButton CaliforniaButton=new JButton("California");
    JButton ChileButton=new JButton("Chile");
    JButton EspanaButton=new JButton("Espana");
    JButton FranciaButton=new JButton("Francia");
    JButton ItaliaButton=new JButton("Italia");
    JButton NZButton=new JButton("New Zealand");
    JButton PortugalButton=new JButton("Portugal");
    JButton PRButton=new JButton("Puerto Rico");
    JButton USAButton=new JButton("USA");
    JScrollPane scroll=new 
    ScrollPane(Title,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
public locationFrame()
{
    super("Wine Application");
    setLayout(null);
    Title.setFont(tFont);
    Title.setLocation(450,0);
    Title.setSize(300,100);
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
    label.setBounds(350,100,500,500);
    backButton.setFont(bFont);
    backButton.setBounds(800,1800,400,100);

    AlemaniButton.setFont(bFont);
    ArgentinaButton.setFont(bFont);
    CaliforniaButton.setFont(bFont);
    ChileButton.setFont(bFont);
    EspanaButton.setFont(bFont);
    FranciaButton.setFont(bFont);
    ItaliaButton.setFont(bFont);
    NZButton.setFont(bFont);
    PortugalButton.setFont(bFont);
    PRButton.setFont(bFont);
    USAButton.setFont(bFont);

    AlemaniButton.setBounds(300,700,600,150);
    ArgentinaButton.setBounds(300,1085,600,150);
    CaliforniaButton.setBounds(300,1470,600,150);
    ChileButton.setBounds(300,1855,600,150);
    EspanaButton.setBounds(300,2240,600,150);
    FranciaButton.setBounds(300,2625,600,150);
    ItaliaButton.setBounds(300,3010,600,150);
    NZButton.setBounds(300,3395,600,150);
    PortugalButton.setBounds(300,3780,600,150);
    PRButton.setBounds(300,4165,600,150);
    USAButton.setBounds(300,4550,600,150);

    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    add(Title);
    add(label);
    add(backButton);
    add(AlemaniButton);
    add(ArgentinaButton);
    add(CaliforniaButton);
    add(ChileButton);
    add(EspanaButton);
    add(FranciaButton);
    add(ItaliaButton);
    add(NZButton);
    add(PortugalButton);
    add(PRButton);
    add(USAButton);

    add(scroll);

    getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    backButton.addActionListener(this);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==backButton)
    {
    mainWineFrame mainFrame=new mainWineFrame();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code and question both have alot of flaws. I'll list some of them and hope I can help you with your problem and improve your code writing.

1. Code format: You should pay attention to the code and naming convention of the language you're using. Java adopts camelCase, and so you shouldn't name your attributes with capital letters.
2. Attribute visibility: I don't know if you did that just as example, but your attributes should always be qualified by a modifier (public, package, private or protected)
3. Your question has alot of code that doesn't really help anyone trying to help you out. Actually, it has even compiling issues. You should pay attention to that as well.

Now as for trying to help you out, on your code you're trying to create a JScrollPane with its viewPort tied to a JLabel (Title). That doesn't make much sense, does it? I think you should read more carefully the documentation about the JScrollPane and keep in mind that the component has a ViewPort, the component that, to put it simple, actually changes when you interact with the scrollbar.

I believe this can at least give you some direction on how to build what you want.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        panel.add(new JButton(""+i));
    }

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

You can find reference material here: [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You are right. I should have used proper code format such as camalCase to simplify things. The code:            
//JScrollPane scroll=new 
JScrollPane(Title,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED); and //add(scroll); were and test to see what could happen since i was experimenting with JScrollPane. Would it be easier to create a panel that has both a JScrollpane and all my buttons and then add that panel to my JFrame?

Comment: No problem, glad I can help. Still, regarding your problem, yes, I believe it would be better if you add all your buttons to a JPanel and set that JPanel as the viewport of your JScrollPane. Afterwards, you shall add that JScrollPane to your JFrame and everything will work out fine. I also included in the answer something that I believe is close to what you want to achieve.